# Re:sub expected string or byte-like object error

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, python-re

```
class REReplacer(object):
   def __init__(self, pattern = R_patterns):
      self.pattern = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

   def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.pattern:
         s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
      return s
```

I have got this code which replaces certain words with their replacements. When I call the method replace of class REplacer,

```
rep=REplacer()
rep.replace("I like oranges")
```

it works perfectly fine with strings but gives an error with list or nested lists.

Error- (re.sub) expected string or bytes-like object.

Is there a way (except for converting the list to string) in order to make the function work of list of sentences? Thanks in advance.
Seems like predefined re.sub takes string as argument. Should I split the words of the list?

Comment: can you share a working example with real regexes ? Also share an example with your lists, it's unclear where you want to put them

Comment: For one - what prevents you to loop over list and call`rep.replace()` with each iteration?

Comment: @buran Yes I have tried that, it is showing the same error.

Comment: My dataset is sentence tokenzied

Comment: Please read my full comment, and [edit] your post to add HOW you would like to use the code, with your list or list

Comment: Hey, so I tried looping over the list and call the function, apparently I thought the dataset remained unchanged as I judged it by on particular word but it was my fault, I didn't add that particular regex rule in my dictionary only. That code was working perfectly fine then. It is kinda embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `text` is a list (or some other iterable type), loop over it and perform the replacements, and return a list of results.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def replace(self, text):
    if isinstance(text, string):
        for (pattern, repl) in self.pattern:
            text = re.sub(pattern, repl, text)
        return text
    elif isinstance(text, Iterable):
        return [self.replace(i) for i in text]
    else:
        raise ValueError('text must be a string or iterable collection')
```